# sys.stdin file extension in Python 2.7

Tags: python, filenames, stdin, file-extension, ends-with

I'm trying to see if a file I input using sys.stdin has a .gz file extension.  Usually I just use a file path directly but when I do sys.stdin it automatically opens it into an reading object.

**Is there any way to get the file name from stdin without doing os.getcwd() or getting a full file path?**

I was trying sys.stdin.endswith('.gz') but it doesn't work (obviously b/c it's not a string) but is there anything I can do with the sys.stdin object to just grab the extension before I proceed to process it?

```
import sys
file = sys.stdin
if file.endswith('.gz'):
    print 'yup'
```

Comment: Maybe post some of the actual code you were trying.

Comment: Why aren't you saving the input into a variable, then checking if the variable has the extension and, if so: process it?

Comment: im saving stdin to a variable

Comment: The object `sys.stdin` is not a string and doesn't have an `endswith()` method.

Comment: I know, I put that in the description too. "I was trying sys.stdin.endswith('.gz') but it doesn't work (obviously b/c it's not a string)" . Do you know of a way to get the name of the file being fed into stdin?

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
import sys
file = sys.stdin
if file.name.endswith('.gz'):
    print 'yup'
```

**Update:**

```
file = raw_input("Enter filename:")
sys.stdin = open(file, 'r')
if sys.stdin.name.endswith('.gz'):
    print 'yup'
```

Comment: it seems the first method can't access file name, see the update

Comment: I tried that but I got there erro>>>sys.stdin = open(file,'r')
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, type found

Comment: you have to give your file name instead of 'file'

Comment: i'm writing a program to run through the terminal so the file name changes with every run

Comment: you can ask the user to input the file name..right?